# UrlMapping Wildcard for @Pathvariable

Tags: java, spring, web.xml, url-pattern, path-variables

I am trying to Define `@PathVariable` with wildcard in Web.xml for url-mapping.
Seems it does not work unless I give the full path in the mapping.
Here is my code.

TrackingController .java - PSEUDO Code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/tracking")
public class JobController implements Runnable {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{countrycode}/{urlID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody

    public RedirectView refreshcache(@PathVariable("countrycode") String countrycode, @PathVariable("urlID") String urlID){

         String Oauthurl="";
         System.out.println(countrycode);
         System.out.println(urlID);
         if (countrycode.equals("India"))
         {
             Oauthurl ="https://www.google.co.in/";
         }
         else
         {
             Oauthurl ="https://www.google.com/";
         }
         RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
            redirectView.setUrl(Oauthurl);
            return redirectView;


        }
```

What I have already Tried is putting the full path and the path with wildcard
in the web.xml

**Full path- Works**

```
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/tracking/India/1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Wildcard - Does not work**

```
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/tracking/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Expected Result with wild card is it would redirect to the Url based on the `@Pathvariable` provided

However it throws **404 Error**

Comment: Why are you trying to double map urls with `web.xml` when you have already mapped them with `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: Do you use component scan? Can you show spring configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify double (*) in the path url to match any string.
here is the example.

```
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/tracking/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback .. unfortunately it still throws error

Comment: What error you are facing right now? 
Can you shared the code through github with simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mapping via `web.xml`. It's already done by `@RequestMapping`.

Following code should work:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/tracking")
public class JobController {


    @GetMapping("/{countryCode}/{urlID}")//removed @ResponseBody
    public RedirectView refreshCache(@PathVariable String countryCode, @PathVariable String urlID) {
        String oauthUrl;

        System.out.println(countryCode);
        System.out.println(urlID);

        if ("India".equalsIgnoreCase(countryCode)) {//Avoid NPE
            oauthUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";
        } else {
            oauthUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
        }
        return new RedirectView(oauthUrl);
    }
}
```

If don't - check configuration. Spring can't find your controllers. [Take a look](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)